# update query that works in both MYSQL and H2

Tags: mysql, h2

I think I have queries for mysql and h2 that both work but can anyone come up with one that works on both?

The table has a foreign key to its own primary key and I want to copy a field value down the heirarchy.

The mysql query looks like this:

```
UPDATE data p, data c SET c.field=p.field WHERE p.id=c.linkid AND p.level = 0;
```

The h2 query looks like this:

```
UPDATE data c SET c.field=(SELECT p.field FROM data p WHERE p.id=c.linkid AND p.level=0)
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM data p WHERE p.id=c.linkid AND p.level=0);
```

The reason for wanting a common query is that the production system is mysql but I have unit tests in maven and I want the tests to run anywhere and not have a dependency on a local mysql database.

Comment: and you are going to retrofit all your queries ?

Comment: If I can get a common query I will change to it, to improve test coverage. At the moment I 'try' the mysql one and if I get an exception I try the h2 one. This is poluting my production code with test queries.

Comment: just curious how onerous the task is of sticking with mysql only, in light of the other onerousity

Comment: It is a fair question. Not too onerous, but I want to be able to check out a maven project and build it without needing to have anything but maven and java on the platform. In fact I have just added a manual switch to a test mysql database to some tests.

Comment: Have you tried using the H2 query in MySQL? It supports correlated subqueries.

Comment: Yup: "ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause"